# archivedDataWithRootObject: on 32 bit app, unarchiveObjectWithData: on 64 bit app

Tags: ios, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

We are updating our app to support 64 bit. When the app was still 32 bit we have persisted some data in the user defaults and file system via `archivedDataWithRootObject:`.

**Can there be any issues when doing `unarchiveObjectWithData:` on this 32 bit data on the 64 bit app?**

I have found these remarks by Apple in the [64-Bit Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/Major64-BitChanges/Major64-BitChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013501-CH2-SW1):

> - Fix alignment issues caused by changes in data type sizes.
> - Ensure that memory structures that are shared between the 32-bit and 64-bit runtimes share a similar layout.

But when looking at the documentation of `NSKeyedArchiver` it says that non-fitting datatypes are automatically coerced.

Answer (score 1):

Generally no, there should be no issue when using archivers changing between 64-bit and 32-bit. If there are this is a major issue that can not be fixed from your perspective as the archiving system should be changed.

Where the issues could arise would be with primitives such as `NSInteger` and `CGFloat` which have a different size in these 2 cases (for some very very dumb reason most likely). The archiver should add the size of the primitive in the data and as far as I know it does. The unarchiver can then interpret the actual primitive and do a correct assignment which will typecast if needed.

You can easily test all this by creating a small application which does the archiving and unarchiving and saving the archived data to some file on the computer. This way you may use the simulator to test if it works as expected both ways.

Those remarks should have nothing to with this, these problems become problems when doing something like copying a buffer:

```
NSInteger floatCount = 100; // number of floats in the buffer
CGFloat *buffer1; // has the data
CGFloat *buffer2; // will be copied to

size_t bufferSize = 4*floatCount; // Not safe as we assume a CGFloat has is 32-bit
size_t bufferSize = 4*sizeof(CGFloat); // Safe

buffer2 = malloc(bufferSize);
memcpy(buffer2, buffer1, bufferSize);
```

Then again there are issues if you wrote some raw data using this Apple defined primitives to some file using either the `NSData` or the raw data themselves you have no way at all to know what is in the buffer and you have a very big problem. So if you are ever doing this you should never ever use these primitive defines but rather create your own or use the pure `C` primitives.